# Setting up ssh between systems using same router

Tags: networking, ssh, wireless-router, ip, routing

I have been trying it to ssh into my ubuntu system from mac. I couldn't get it working though. I am using a DIR-816 as my router.

Here are the configurations:
mac:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether f4:5c:89:bf:1f:db 
    inet6 fe80::f65c:89ff:febf:1fdb%en0 prefixlen 64 duplicated scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.104 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

ubuntu:

```
wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:eb:42:0f:8c:6e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I cannot access my router settings page (192.168.0.1) from these ip. To access it, I need to change my ip to something like 192.168.0.x
Could someone help me figure out why it isn't working?

The default gateway is 192.168.1.100

`arp -a` from the client mac :

```
? (192.168.1.1) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.100) at 0:d0:cb:0:0:5 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.102) at 4c:eb:42:f:8c:6e on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.103) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.255) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

So it can see the ubuntu server (192.168.1.102)

Comment: "I need to change my ip to something like" - What do you need to change it to exactly?  Are you sure your using the correct intranet address for the SSH server?

Comment: For example to access from mac, I am changing it to 192.168.0.104

Comment: You have confirmed your Mac is assigned that address?  I asked because, you don't seem sure, what address your router is assigned.

Comment: @Ramhound Presently they are assigned to 192.168.1.104 and 192.168.1.102 . I can access the internet from these ip but not the router settings page. To access the router settings page I change the ip to 192.168.0.104 for mac and 192.168.0.102 for ubuntu. When on these ip I cannot access the internet